# How to calculate scalar curvature, Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?

Tags: symbolic, physics, tensors, differential-geometry

I am seeking a convenient and effective way to calculate such geometric quantities. I've used packages like [`TensoriaCalc`](http://www.stargazing.net/yizen/Tensoria.html), but they don't work at all time. Sometimes, I run into the following error:

> Symbol `Tensor` is Protected.
>   Symbol `TensorType` is Protected.
>   Symbol `TensorName` is Protected.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Clear [i, j, φ, τ, σ] 
q["case"] = Metric[ SubMinus[i], SubMinus[j], 
    E^(2 φ[σ]) (\[DifferentialD]τ^2 + \[DifferentialD] σ^2), 
    CoordinateSystem -> {τ, σ}, TensorName -> "T", StartIndex -> 1 ]
```

I think the above is correct, since I merely modified the example from the package manual. It gives me the correct answer sometimes (if I only use one notebook).

Also, I ran the codes from the chapter "General Relativity" in the book "*Mathmatica* for theoretical physics" by Gerd Baumann, but none of them work

Is there more efficient way to calculate them? Please give me some suggestions about this.

Comment: Also Hartle has mathematica notebooks on his website that can do everything from the Christofell symbols to the Einstein tensor. http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~gravitybook/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question via Google. Thanks for using my `TensoriaCalc` package!

My response is probably too late, but I believe the problem you cited

> Symbol Tensor is Protected.
>   Symbol TensorType is Protected.
>   Symbol TensorName is Protected.

is because you loaded `TensoriaCalc` more than once in the same kernel session.

When writing the package, I had to `Protect` all the symbols used in the package, such as `Tensor`, `Metric`, etc. This means their definitions cannot be altered by an external user, as otherwise, it will create inconsistencies. This is why loading `TensoriaCalc` more than once gives an error, because you are essentially trying to define these symbols yet again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 79):

### General remarks

In General Relativity we work in a 4-dimentional Lorentzian manifold i.e. there is a metric tensor $g$ of signature $(+,-,-,-)$ or $(-,+,+,+)$. Theses signatures are mathematically equivalent and we choose the latter because of certain quite formal aspects even though there are some physically relevant reasons for choosing the former one. In a neighbourhood of any point we choose a local chart $xx = (x^{1},x^{2},x^{3},x^{4})$ where the metric tensor is represented by real functions $g_{\alpha\beta}(x^{\mu})$ i.e. $g = g_{\alpha\beta}(x^{\mu}) dx^{\alpha}\otimes dx^{\beta}$  (We enumerate indices by $1,2,3,4$ unlike traditionally $0,1,2,3$ for representing tensors in `Mathematica` by `Table`s and accessing their entries by `Part` e.g. `[[1,1]]`). Now assuming [the Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) we need the following objects :

- inverse metric $g^{\mu \nu}$ : (i.e. $g^{\mu \nu} g_{\nu\alpha} = \delta^{\mu}_{\alpha} )\quad$ ( `InverseMetric[g][[μ, ν]]` )
- Christoffel symbols (of the second kind) $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\sigma}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\alpha}\left\{\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\nu}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}+\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}}-\frac{\partial g_{\nu\sigma}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right\}\quad$ (`ChristoffelSymbol[g, xx][[μ, ν, σ]]` )
- Riemann tensor $R^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\lambda\sigma}=\partial_{\lambda}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\sigma}-\partial_{\sigma}
  \Gamma^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\lambda}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\rho\lambda}\Gamma^{\rho}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\sigma}-\Gamma^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\rho\sigma}\Gamma^{\rho}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\lambda}\quad$

  ( `RiemannTensor[g, xx][[μ, ν, λ, σ]]` )
- Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}=R^{\lambda}_{\phantom{\lambda}\mu\lambda\nu}\quad$ ( `RicciTensor[g, xx][[μ, ν]]` )
- Ricci scalar $R = R^{\mu}_{\phantom{\lambda}\mu}\quad$ (`RicciScalar[g, xx]`)

### A straightforward implementation

It will be convenient to define geometrical objects in the following order (this may become a frame for developing a package):

```
InverseMetric[ g_] := Simplify[ Inverse[g] ]
ChristoffelSymbol[g_, xx_] := 
    Block[{n, ig, res}, 
           n = 4; ig = InverseMetric[ g]; 
           res = Table[(1/2)*Sum[ ig[[i,s]]*(-D[ g[[j,k]], xx[[s]]] + 
                                              D[ g[[j,s]], xx[[k]]] 
                                            + D[ g[[s,k]], xx[[j]]]), 
                                  {s, 1, n}], 
                       {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
           Simplify[ res]
         ]
RiemannTensor[g_, xx_] := 
    Block[{n, Chr, res}, 
           n   = 4; Chr = ChristoffelSymbol[ g, xx];
           res = Table[  D[ Chr[[i,k,m]], xx[[l]]] 
                       - D[ Chr[[i,k,l]], xx[[m]]]
                       + Sum[ Chr[[i,s,l]]*Chr[[s,k,m]], {s, 1, n}]
                       - Sum[ Chr[[i,s,m]]*Chr[[s,k,l]], {s, 1, n}], 
                        {i, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}, {m, 1, n}]; 
           Simplify[ res]
         ]
RicciTensor[g_, xx_] :=
    Block[{Rie, res, n}, 
           n = 4; Rie = RiemannTensor[ g, xx]; 
           res = Table[ Sum[ Rie[[ s,i,s,j]], 
                             {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; 
           Simplify[ res]
         ] 
RicciScalar[g_, xx_] := 
    Block[{Ricc,ig, res, n}, 
           n = 4; Ricc = RicciTensor[ g, xx]; ig = InverseMetric[ g];
           res = Sum[ ig[[s,i]] Ricc[[s,i]], {s, 1, n}, {i, 1, n}];
           Simplify[res]
        ]
```

Following this way one could define another interesting geometrical objects e.g. the Weyl tensor $
C_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}=R_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}-\left(g_{\mu[\lambda}R_{\nu]\sigma}-g_{\nu[\lambda}R_{\sigma]\mu}\right)+\frac{1}{3}R g_{\mu[\lambda}g_{\nu]\sigma}$

### Schwarzschild-like ansatz for a static spherically symmetric spacetime

In order to start with a concrete example let's define coordinates and a metric tensor of 4-dimensional static spherically symmetric Lorentzian spacetime :

```
xx = {t, x, θ, ϕ};

g  = { {-E^(2 ν[x]), 0         ,   0,            0},
       {          0, E^(2 λ[x]),   0,            0},
       {          0,          0, x^2,            0},
       {          0,          0,   0, x^2 Sin[θ]^2}};
```

Now let's compute `RicciScalar` :

```
RicciScalar[g, xx]
```

[image]

If you want to solve `Einstein` equations of a vacuum spacetime (e.g. the Schwarzschild spacetime) you should solve equations : `RicciTensor[g, xx] == 0`.

```
 RicciTensor[g, xx]
```

[image]

Now you have to choose two independent equations, e.g.

```
eqs={ λ'[x] ( 2 + x ν'[x]) -x ( ν'[x]^2+ ν''[x]), -1 + E^(2 λ[x]) + x ( λ'[x] - ν'[x])};
```

and solve this system of ordinary differential equations :

```
eqs[[1]] == 0;
eqs[[2]] == 0;
```

with appropriate boundary conditions. In case of the Schwarzschild solution that should be `g -> g0` at infinity, where `g0` is the Minkowski metric.

### de-Sitter spacetime

Let's find e.g. scalar curvature of de-Sitter spacetime (`a` is a constant):

```
Clear[g]
g = {{-(1 - x^2/a^2),               0,   0,            0},
     {             0, 1/(1 - x^2/a^2),   0,            0},
     {             0,               0, x^2,            0},
     {             0,               0,   0, x^2 Sin[θ]^2}};
RicciScalar[g, xx]
```

> ```
>  12/a^2
> ```

Thus we have shown that de-Sitter spacetime has a constant scalar curvature.

Comment: Thank everybody above for your patience and help. I have some seminars those days, I will come back soon and give the feedback.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `n=Length[g]` instead of `n=4`? This helps generalize the package to more dimensions.

Comment: @cartonn This is a part of my larger package I wrote some time ago. In fact I needed only `n = 4` case because of another functions therein, which were defined properly assuming that there were `4` dimensions. A generalization shouldn't be difficult but it would need a bit more than changing only `n = 4` to `n = Length[g]`.

Answer (score 18):

This one might be a starter to calculate the tensors.

```
partialDer[T_, vars_] := D[T, #] & /@ vars // Simplify

christoffelSymbols[metric_, coord_] :=

 Module[{dg = partialDer[metric, coord], 
   inverse = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]},
  inverse.(Transpose[dg, {2, 1, 3}] + Transpose[dg, {3, 2, 1}] - dg)/
    2 // Simplify]

curvTensor[christ_, var_] :=

 Module[{temp1, temp2, i, h, j, k, s, n},
  n = Length[var];
  temp1[i_, h_, j_, k_] := D[christ[[i, h, j]], var[[k]]];
  temp2[i_, h_, j_, k_] := 
   temp1[i, h, k, j] - temp1[i, h, j, k] + 
    Sum[christ[[s, h, k]] christ[[i, s, j]] - 
      christ[[s, h, j]] christ[[i, s, k]], {s, n}];
  Simplify[Table[temp2[i, h, j, k], {i, n}, {h, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]]
  ]

ricciTensor[curv_] :=
 Module[{k, j, n},
  n = Length[curv[[1, 1]]];
  Table[Sum[curv[[k, i, k, j]], {k, n}], {i, n}, {j, n}] // 
    ExpandAll // Simplify
  ]
```

This is the usage of the functions used:

```
partialDer::usage = "partialDer[T,vars] builts the list of the \
partial derivatives \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(i\)]\)T of \
tensor T w.r.t. the variables of list \"vars\".  The first index of \
the produced list will be the derivative index."

christoffelSymbols::usage = "christoffelSymbols[metric, vars] gives \
the Christoffel-Symbols christ\[LeftDoubleBracket]i,j,k\
\[RightDoubleBracket] with variables of list vars and the metric \
Tensor metric. The first indes will be the \"upper\" index."

curvTensor::usage = "curvTensor[christ,vars] takes the Christoffel \
symbols \"christ\" with variables vars and calcules the Rieman \
curvature tensor. The first index will be the \
\"upper\\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote] index."

ricciTensor::usage = "ricciTensor[curv] takes the Riemann curvarture \
tensor \"curv\" and calculates the Ricci tensor"
```

**Example**

First we need to give a metric Tensor *gM* and the variables list *vars* we will use, then we calculate the Christoffel symbols, the Riemann Curvature tensor and the Ricci tensor:

```
vars = {u, v}; gM = {{1, 0}, {0, Sin[u]^2}};
christ = christoffelSymbols[gM, vars]
curv = curvTensor[christ, vars]
ricciTensor[curv]
```

Output:

> `{{{0, 0}, {0, -Cos[u] Sin[u]}}, {{0, Cot[u]}, {Cot[u], 0}}}`
>
> `{{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, Sin[u]^2}, {-Sin[u]^2, 0}}}, {{{0, -1}, {1, 
>          0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}}`
>
> `{{1, 0}, {0, Sin[u]^2}}`

This works for 3 and 4 dimensional Tensors as well. I only wanted to keep the example small.

Answer (score 12):

Since Version 9, functions to do this have been built into Mathematica but not documented. They live in the SymbolicTensors package which underlies `CoordinateChartData`, `CoordinateTransform`, and related functions.  You could add the context to `$ContextPath` to save needing to type it everywhere, though I won't do that in the example below.

They easiest way to get there is to define a "patch".  This can be done in various ways, but for a diagonal metric tensor the easiest way is scale factors.  Here I'll use Minkowski in spherical coordinates as my example:

```
vars = {t, r, th, p};
patch = SymbolicTensors`ScaleFactorGeometryPatch[{-1, 1, r, r Sin[th]}, vars];
```

There is also an `OrthonormalFrameGeometryPatch` which takes a matrix in the first argument, interpreted as the matrix which takes 1-forms to an orthonormal frame, and a `RiemannianGeometryPatch` which takes a metric as a `Tensor` object in the first argument.

Once you have a patch, you can query available properties:

```
patch["Properties"]
(*{"CotangentBasis", "InverseMetric", "InverseMetricTensor", "LeviCivitaConnection", 
   "Metric", "MetricTensor", "OrthonormalBasis", "RicciScalar", "RicciTensor", 
   "RiemannTensor", "ScaleFactors", "TangentBasis", "VolumeFactor"}*)
```

Simiarly to `CoordinateChartData`, you can extract the property with a variable list which is the evaluation point:

```
patch["RicciTensor", vars] // Simplify
(*SymbolicTensors`Tensor[{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, 
    {SymbolicTensors`CotangentBasis[{t,r,th,p}],SymbolicTensors`CotangentBasis[{t,r,th,p}]}
  ]*)
```

Note that what you call the Christoffel symbols of the first kind is what we call the `"LeviCivitaConnection"`.

For the basic tensorial properties, we have corresponding functions, but you need to take care with the arguments.  `RiemmanTensor` and `RicciTensor` take a connection followed by variables, since they make sense for non-metric tensors.  `LeviCivitaConnection`, `RicciScalar`, and `EinsteinTensors` take a a metric.  In all cases it should be a proper `Tensor` object as returned above.

I'm not sure why `"EinsteinTensor"` isn't an available property of a patch.  Probably just an oversight.  If I get enough requests here, I'll add it.

Comment: These look too nice to be kept undocumented. Hopefully some day... anyway, since `"EinsteinTensor"` isn't available yet, what could be done in the meantime to get it?

Comment: `Plus` and `Times` understand `Tensor` addition and scalar multiplication, so you can just form it in the obvious way from `"RicciTensor"`, `"RicciScalar"`, and `"MetricTensors"`.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few packages in Mathsource already available they are

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8329/

and

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4781/

for the basics both programs do the same thing but the first one has more functionality.

Answer (score 4):

A very good tutorial may be found here:

http://www.physics.ucsb.edu/~gravitybook/math/curvature.nb