# How do I define a tensor from another tensor with summations?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, tensors

Let's say we have a rank 2 tensor $g_{ij}$. This is basically a list with a `Depth` of 2. Now I'd like to calculate another tensor

$\Gamma_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}g^{ks}g_{is}=\frac{1}{2}(g^{k1}g_{i1}+g^{k2}g_{i2}+g^{k3}g_{i3}+...)$,

which is another list of `Depth` 2. For instance, to find a specific element, one would simply say

$\Gamma_{23}=\frac{1}{2}(g^{21}g_{31}+g^{22}g_{32}+g^{23}g_{33}+...)$.

We also know that $g^{ij}$ (which I will call `ginv` is found by taking the inverse of $g_{ij}$, i.e. `ginv=Inverse[g]`.

I'm having trouble defining $\Gamma$ index by index. I thought of using `Array`, but I can't really come up with a solution. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't there be also $g_{\text{kj}}$ in $\Gamma _{\text{ij}}$ definition? I think you may be interested in Artes answer for [... Ricci tensor ... in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8895/5478)

Comment: The definitions are not correct, and yes that's what I will try to implement eventually. For now, I was just trying to do some basic tensor math.

Comment: Actually, yes that answer has everything I wanted. I'll delete this question :)

Comment: You don't have to. It can be marked as duplicate and stay here as a road sign for future visitors.

Comment: All right then, I'll let it stay. I might post a basic answer, adapted from that other question you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to do so but first reformulate your question so formulas are correct and it will be consistent q&a.

Comment: @cartonn Precisely (mathematically) Christoffel symbols are not tensors.

Comment: I think you are looking for `TensorContract` (for your first equation).