# Package for symbolic computation of christoffel symbols and parallel transports in Riemannian geometry, given the metric

Tags: image-processing, topology, computational-geometry

I've no knowledge in mathematica (but I do in matlab), but I'd really appreciate if someone could mention what is/are the best and easy to learn mathematica package(s) for symbolic and numerical (both, really) computation of Riemannian geometry, specially Christoffel symbols, sectional curvature, and parallel transport along a given curve on M, given the topological type of the manifold M and the Riemannian metric g on M.

To explain myself a little more: in order to symbolically compute the Christoffel symbols, I've to invert a matrix and compute the symbolic and numerical derivatives w.r.t. the matrix. These matrices come from observations of medical data and are d by n matrices with n being a huge number, and d is normally 2 or 3.

After that, I've to compute the parallel transport along a curve c, which'll involve solving a system of first order linear ordinary differential equation with matrix entries depending on the derivative c' and the Christoffel symbols.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [8895](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8895/134) will help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Will do, absolutely!

Comment: If you were a physicist specializing in general relativity, I would suggest `xAct` with `xCoba` for the Christoffels, but it requires extensive knowledge of differential geometry. There exist less complicated packages, but I have no experience with them.

Comment: Thanks auxsvr: I do have extensive knowledge of the pure theoretical part of differential geometry, but zero knowledge about the how to put the syntaxes in mathematica or any other programs. Will this still work for me?

Comment: Please read my answer below. I am not familiar with using diff. Geometry with medical data. Would you perhaps briefly explain what these large data matrices represent and what kind of manifolds you want to detect/describe  with Christoffels/ curvature

Comment: Thank you! I'll post one more comment. The manifold M has its tangent space T as $(\mathbb{R}^d)^n$ and $M$ itself is an open subset of T. The metric: you choose tangent vectors $c,d\in (\mathbb{R}^d)^n=(\mathbb{R}^{dn}$ at $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n)\in M, x_i\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, then $g_x(c,d):=c^{T}S(x)d$, where $S(x)$ is a $dn$ by $dn$ matrix, which is written as $nXn$ blocks, and the $(i,j)$-th block is a $dXd$ matrix, which is $exp(-0.5{\sigma}^{-2}.||x_i-x_j||^2). I_d$. Want to compute its Christoffel symbols, symbolically and numerically.Then the curvatures at least numerically.

Answer (score 5):

The most powerful tensor package suit for MMA (and arguably for any CAS) is xAct. It uses the full machinery of diff geometry (fiber bundles, connections, forms, ect) and a powerful canonicalization algorithm, both symbolically and numerically. Obviouly you can use just a fraction of this power. I am the developer of xPrint, the GUI interface to xAct. With xPrint you can use many of xAct tools with "point and click" ease. It would shield you from some MMA technicalities. We have an active forum to help newcomers. The packages are free.

[xAct.es](http://www.xact.es) is the main site

[xPrint](https://sites.google.com/site/xprintforxact/xprintforxact) main site

Comment: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/428/what-third-party-packages-do-you-use is a list to most popular packages for MMA

Comment: Thank you, will surely try it. Although it's free, I've to still install mathematica (not free), right?

Comment: Yes you need to install mathematica. It is not free, but there are several licence options. All equally powerful...very powerful.