# Solving the values of Christoffel symbols from a given metric tensor

Tags: tensors, astronomy

Is there any easy mathematica package by which I can solve the Christoffel symbols from a given metric tensor?

Comment: Check here (duplicate?):  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80850/package-for-symbolic-computation-of-christoffel-symbols-and-parallel-transports

Comment: Some of these may help (not sure) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19938/12

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind information.