# Ricci tensor with Mathematica

Tags: tensors

I'm trying for first time to write a Ricci tensor with *Mathematica*.
The code I've written is this:

```
Ricci := Simplify[Table[(Sum[D[GammaTesiGenerale[[i, k, m]], coord[[i]]], {i, 1, 4}] -
  Sum[D[GammaTesiGenerale[[i, k, i]], coord[[m]]], {i, 1, 4}] + 
 Sum[Sum[GammaTesiGenerale[[i, s, i]], {i, 1, 4}]*
   GammaTesiGenerale[[s, k, m]], {s, 1, 4}] - 
 Sum[Sum[GammaTesiGenerale[[i, s, m]]*
    GammaTesiGenerale[[s, k, i]], {i, 1, 4}], {s, 1, 4}]), {k, 1, 
4}, {m, 1, 4}]]
```

Where `GammaTesiGenerale` is:

```
GammaTesiGenerale := Simplify[Table[(1/2*
 Sum[(m[[i, s]])*(D[g[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
     D[g[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - D[g[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, 
   4}]), {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}]]
```

g is the metric

```
{{n[t]^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -a[t]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -a[t]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -a[t]^2}}
```

And `coord := {t, x, y, z}`

My problem is that after evaluation mathematica gives me this:

> Part specification 1[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>   Part specification 1[[1,2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>   Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

I also get a really large matrix with many of `-1[[2, 1]]`. I've no idea of where these are coming form.

Have you an idea about what is happening?

---

I've evaluated Ricci[[1, 1]], for example.

Comment: Davide, could you show exactly what you evaluated to obtain your result? All the code you show uses `SetDelayed` (i.e. `:=`) so nothing is evaluated yet.

Comment: Also, take a look at this questions that may be very relevant to what you are trying to do: [How to calculate scalar curvature Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8895/27951), and at these packages: [Riemannian Geometry & Tensor Calculus @ Mathematica](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/RGTC/) and perhaps [Ricci - A Mathematica package for doing tensor calculations in differential geometry](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/).

Comment: One of the best and most powerful packages for handling Riemannian Geometry and General Relativity is: http://www.xact.es/