# Scalar from tensor contraction

Tags: symbolic, tensors

I'm trying to calculate the Kretschmann scalar in mathematica, it is given by:

> $c = R^{abcd} R_{abcd}$

Where $R^{abcd}$ is the Riemann tensor. I'm following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem) MSE post so I modified it to get the corresponding $R^{abcd}$ in the following manner:

```
RiemannTensorarriba[g_, xx_] := Block[{n, Rie, ig, res}, n = 4; 
Rie = RiemannTensor[g, xx]; 
ig = InverseMetric[g];                       
res = Table[
Sum[ig[[i, a]]*ig[[j, b]]*ig[[k, c]]*Rie[l, a, b, c], {a, 1, 
  n}, {b, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 
 1, n}];
Simplify[res]]
```

And I'm raising the first index in the Riemann Tensor of the MSE:

```
Riemannabajo[g_, xx_] := Block[{n, rie, res}, n = 4;
rie = RiemannTensor[g, xx];
res = Table[
Sum[g[[i, j]]*rie[[j, a, b, c]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {a, 1, 
 n}, {b, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}];
Simplify[res]]
```

Now if I have the both tensors that I need, so to contract the indices I'm trying both:

```
Riemannabajo[g,xx].RiemannTensorArriba[g,xx]
```

And programing it via a summation like:

```
Kreztchman[g_, xx_] := Block[{n, Rie, Riea, res}, n = 4;
Rie = Riemannabajo[g, xx];
Riea = RiemannTensorarriba[g, xx];
res = Sum[
Riea[[i, k, l, m]]*Rie[[i, k, l, m]], {i, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1,
  n}, {m, 1, n}];
Simplify[res]]
```

But both answers don't give me a scalar, instead I get some kind of tensor. Where I'm missing the point?

Edit: In order to be consistent, Im using the solution of the MSE as proposed by @Arte, ie:

```
InverseMetric[g_]:=Simplify[Inverse[g]]

ChristoffelSymbol[g_,xx_]:=Block[{n,ig,res},n=4;ig=InverseMetric[g];
res=Table[(1/2)*Sum[ig[[i,s]]*(-
D[g[[j,k]],xx[[s]]]+D[g[[j,s]],xx[[k]]]+D[g[[s,k]],xx[[j]]]),{s,1,n}],{i,1,n},{j,1,n},{k,1,n}];
Simplify[res]]
RiemannTensor[g_,xx_]:=Block[{n,Chr,res},n=4;Chr=ChristoffelSymbol[g,xx];
res=Table[D[Chr[[i,k,m]],xx[[l]]]-D[Chr[[i,k,l]],xx[[m]]]+Sum[Chr[[i,s,l]]*Chr[[s,k,m]],{s,1,n}]-Sum[Chr[[i,s,m]]*Chr[[s,k,l]],{s,1,n}],{i,1,n},{k,1,n},{l,1,n},{m,1,n}];
Simplify[res]]

RicciTensor[g_,xx_]:=Block[{Rie,res,n},n=4;Rie=RiemannTensor[g,xx];
    res=Table[Sum[Rie[[s,i,s,j]],{s,1,n}],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}];
    Simplify[res]]
RicciScalar[g_,xx_]:=Block[{Ricc,ig,res,n},n=4;Ricc=RicciTensor[g,xx];ig=InverseMetric[g];
res=Sum[ig[[s,i]] Ricc[[s,i]],{s,1,n},{i,1,n}];
Simplify[res]]

RiemannTensorarriba[g_,xx_]:=Block[{n,Rie,ig,res},n=4;
Rie=RiemannTensor[g,xx];
ig=InverseMetric[g];
res=Table[Sum[ig[[i,a]]*ig[[j,b]]*ig[[k,c]]*Rie[l,a,b,c],{a,1,n},{b,1,n},{c,1,n}],{i,1,n},{j,1,n},{k,1,n},{l,1,n}];
Simplify[res]]

Riemannabajo[g_,xx_]:=Block[{n,rie,res},n=4;
rie=RiemannTensor[g,xx];
res=Table[Sum[g[[i,j]]*rie[[j,a,b,c]],{j,1,n}],{i,1,n},{a,1,n},{b,1,n},{c,1,n}];
Simplify[res]]
```

And I'm trying to calculete the Kretschmann invariant to the following metric:

```
xx = {t, x, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
g = {{-(1 - x^2/a^2), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/(1 - x^2/a^2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
x^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, x^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};
```

Comment: Even after copying the definitions from the linked question, your code does not execute successfully, instead generating a slew of errors. Please make sure that you a) include all relevant definitions and parameter values, and b) make sure that your code will execute correctly in a fresh Mathematica session. We won't be able to help otherwise.

Comment: I tought it to be complete. Anyway there is the edit with all the code in order to work

Comment: Jasimud, your RiemannTensors are rank-4 tensors. According to the docs, `Dot` contracts the last index in its first arguments with the first index in its second argument; for your tensors, this will result in a tensor of rank 6, and not a scalar, so this can't possibly work. Perhaps you want to look at [`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) or [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract.html).

Comment: Since it's a rank-4 tensor in order tu apply Inner, or TensorContract I would need to put the list of indices I need to contract, for example only for the first pair of indices it would be {1,1,a,b,c},{2,2,a,b,c}{3,3,a,b,c}{4,4,a,b,c}, and then I need to expand all other 3 indeces, there are lot's of contractions, there must be a simpler way than just counting them by hand

Comment: The capitalization of variable names is inconsistent (e.g., `RiemannTensorarriba` vs `RiemannTensorArriba`).  Pleass make sure that you don't have stray definitions by restarting the kernel.  It might be helpful to English speakers to replace `arriba` and `abajo` by `Up` and `Down`.  Your approach with `Sum[...,{i,1,n},{j,1,n},{k,1,n},{l,1,n}]` seems reasonable, but it seems that `Riemannabajo[[i,j,k,l]]` should be `Riemannabajo[g,xx][[i,j,k,l]]` if I read the code correctly.  The order of indices in `RiemannTensorarriba` seems wrong (should be `l`, `i`, `j`, `k`).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I edited the post with the full code I was using for the scalar, it still gives me some higher rank tensor, and I don't seem to grasp why or why the order of the contraction for RiemannTensorarriba should be l i j k

Comment: `Rie[l,a,b,c]` should have double brackets.  Perhaps that mistake occurs elsewhere: you can check the dimension of various parts by `Dimensions[Riemannabajo[g,xx]]` etc.  As for order of indices, if I read `Sum[ig[[i, a]]*ig[[j, b]]*ig[[k, c]]*Rie[l, a, b, c], {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}]` correctly it computes $g^{ia}g^{jb}g^{kc}R^l{}_{abc} = R^{lijk}$ not $R^{ijkl}$.  But maybe `Rie[[l, a, b, c]]` means $R_{abc}{}^l$.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some extra bits feel free to remove

```
   ClearAll["Global`*"];

n = 4;
coord = {t, x, y, z};

(*For raising/lowering latin indices like a, b, ...*)
η = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
η // MatrixForm;
inveta = Inverse[η];
inveta // MatrixForm;

(*"e-Metric";*)
e = {{\[ScriptCapitalN][t], 0, 0, 0}, {0, \[ScriptA][t], 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, \[ScriptA][t], 0}, {0, 0, 0, \[ScriptA][t]}};
\[ScriptCapitalN][t] = -1;
e // MatrixForm;
dete = Det[e];
(*Inverse e-Metric*)
inve = Inverse[e];
inve // MatrixForm;
detinve = Det[inve];

g := g = Simplify[Table[
    ParallelSum[ η[[a, b]]*e[[a, μ]]*e[[b, ν]]
     , {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]
    , {μ, 1, n}, {ν, 1, n}]]
g // MatrixForm;
(*g is used to LOWER indices for Greek indices μ, ν*)
invg = Inverse[g];
invg // MatrixForm;
(*invg is used to RAISE indices for Greek indices μ, ν*)

(* In the form Γ^{x}_{xx}*)
affine := affine = Simplify[Table[(1/2)*Sum[(invg[[i, s]])*
        (D[g[[s, j]], coord[[k]] ] +
          D[g[[s, k]], coord[[j]] ] - D[g[[j, k]], coord[[s]] ]), {s, 
        1, n}],
     {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}] ];
listaffine := 
  Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
     0], {ToString[Γ[i, j, k]], 
     affine[[i, j, k]]}] , {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}];
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {2, 2}];

(* In the form R^{x}_{xxx} *)
riemann := riemann = Simplify[Table[
     D[affine[[i, j, l]], coord[[k]] ] - 
      D[affine[[i, j, k]], coord[[l]] ] +
      Sum[
       affine[[s, j, l]] affine[[i, k, s]] - 
        affine[[s, j, k]] affine[[i, l, s]],
       {s, 1, n}],
     {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}] ];
listriemann := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[riemann[[i, j, k, l]], 0], {ToString[R[i, j, k, l]],
     riemann[[i, j, k, l]]}] , {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1,
    k - 1}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listriemann], Null], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {2, 2}];

(* In the form R_{xxxx} *)
riemann1 := riemann1 = Simplify[Table[
    Sum[
     g[[μ, μ1]]*riemann[[μ1, ν, ρ, σ]]
     , {μ1, 1, n}]
    , {μ, 1, n}, {ν, 1, n}, {ρ, 1, n}, {σ, 1, n}]]
listriemann1 := 
  Table[If[UnsameQ[riemann1[[μ, ν, ρ, σ]], 
     0], {ToString[R1[μ, ν, ρ, σ]], 
     riemann1[[μ, ν, ρ, σ]]}] , {μ, 1, 
    n}, {ν, 1, n}, {ρ, 1, n}, {σ, 1, ρ - 1}];
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listriemann1], Null], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {2, 2}];

(* In the form R^{xxxx} *)
riemann2 := riemann2 = Simplify[Table[
    Sum[
     Sum[
      Sum[
       invg[[ν1, ν]]*invg[[ρ1, ρ]]*
        invg[[σ1, σ]]*
        riemann[[μ, ν1, ρ1, σ1]]
       , {ν1, 1, n}]
      , {ρ1, 1, n}]
     , {σ1, 1, n}]
    , {μ, 1, n}, {ν, 1, n}, {ρ, 1, n}, {σ, 1, n}]]
listriemann2 := 
  Table[If[UnsameQ[riemann2[[μ, ν, ρ, σ]], 
     0], {ToString[R2[μ, ν, ρ, σ]], 
     riemann2[[μ, ν, ρ, σ]]}] , {μ, 1, 
    n}, {ν, 1, n}, {ρ, 1, n}, {σ, 1, ρ - 1}];
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listriemann2], Null], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {2, 2}];

KretschmannScalar = Simplify[
  Sum[riemann1[[a, b, c, d]]*riemann2[[a, b, c, d]], {a, 1, n}, {b, 1,
     n}, {c, 1, n}, {d, 1, n}]]
```

With that input metric I got this answer:

$\frac{12 \left(\mathit{a}(t)^2 \mathit{a}''(t)^2+\mathit{a}'(t)^4\right)}{\mathit{a}(t)^4}$