# Compute covariant derivative in Mathematica

Tags: tensors, calculus-and-analysis, differential-geometry

I need to compute covariant derivatives in Mathematica. Searching online I just found the package "Ricci" which only does symbolic computations: I instead need to do actual computations.

This is what I mean: consider $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. In these coordinates I want to define a Riemannian metric by the coefficients $g_{ij}$, $i,j=1,\dots,4$. Then I would like to define two vector fields $u=\sum_iu_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i};\ v=\sum_jv_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ by their coefficients $u_i,v_j$ (which are functions in coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$). Finally I would like Mathematica to compute the covariant derivative $\nabla_uv.$

Is there some package which will do the computation? If not, can you suggest me an algorithm which will do it?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.xact.es/xCoba/index.html

Comment: Here is a direct pedestrian approach: [How to calculate scalar curvature Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some code I wrote a while back:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SetAttributes[Rs, Constant]
$Assumptions = Rs > 0;
Coordinates = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
dim = Length[Coordinates];

MetricTensorLL = {{(1 - Rs/r), 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1 - Rs/r)^-1, 0, 
 0}, {0, 0, -r^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};

MetricTensorUU := MetricTensorUU = Simplify[Inverse[MetricTensorLL]];

ChristoffelSymbolsULL := 
 ChristoffelSymbolsULL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[1/2 Sum[
    MetricTensorUU[[#1, \[Lambda]]] (D[
     MetricTensorLL[[#3, \[Lambda]]], Coordinates[[#2]]] + 
      D[MetricTensorLL[[\[Lambda], #2]], Coordinates[[#3]]] - 
       D[MetricTensorLL[[#2, #3]], 
        Coordinates[[\[Lambda]]]]), {\[Lambda], dim}] &, {dim, 
         dim, dim}];

ChristoffelSymbolsLLL := 
 ChristoffelSymbolsLLL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[1/2 (D[MetricTensorLL[[#1, #2]], Coordinates[[#3]]] + 
    D[MetricTensorLL[[#1, #3]], Coordinates[[#2]]] - 
     D[MetricTensorLL[[#2, #3]], Coordinates[[#1]]]) &, {dim, dim,
      dim}];

RiemannCurvatureTensorULLL := 
 RiemannCurvatureTensorULLL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[D[ChristoffelSymbolsULL[[#1, #2, #4]], Coordinates[[#3]]] - 
    D[ChristoffelSymbolsULL[[#1, #2, #3]], Coordinates[[#4]]] + 
     Sum[ChristoffelSymbolsULL[[#1, #3, \[Epsilon]]] \
      ChristoffelSymbolsULL[[\[Epsilon], #2, #4]], {\[Epsilon], dim}] - 
       Sum[ChristoffelSymbolsULL[[#1, #4, \[Epsilon]]] \
        ChristoffelSymbolsULL[[\[Epsilon], #2, #3]], {\[Epsilon], 
         dim}] &, {dim, dim, dim, dim}];

RiemannCurvatureTensorLLLL := 
 RiemannCurvatureTensorLLLL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[Sum[
    MetricTensorLL[[#1, \[Tau]]] \
     RiemannCurvatureTensorULLL[[\[Tau], #2, #3, #4]], {\[Tau], 
      dim}] &, {dim, dim, dim, dim}];

RiemannCurvatureTensorUUUU := 
 RiemannCurvatureTensorUUUU = 
  Simplify@
   Array[Sum[
    MetricTensorUU[[#2, \[Alpha]]] MetricTensorUU[[#3, \[Beta]]] \
     MetricTensorUU[[#4, \[Gamma]]] RiemannCurvatureTensorULLL[[#1, \
      \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]]], {\[Alpha], dim}, {\[Beta], 
       dim}, {\[Gamma], dim}] &, {dim, dim, dim, dim}];

RiemannCurvatureTensorLL := 
 RiemannCurvatureTensorLL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[Sum[
    RiemannCurvatureTensorULLL[[\[Lambda], #1, \[Lambda], #2]], {\
     \[Lambda], dim}] &, {dim, dim}];

RiemannCurvatureTensorUL := 
 RiemannCurvatureTensorUL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[Sum[
    MetricTensorUU[[#1, \[Lambda]]] RiemannCurvatureTensorLL[[\
     \[Lambda], #2]], {\[Lambda], dim}] &, {dim, dim}];

ScalarCurvature := ScalarCurvature = Tr[RiemannCurvatureTensorUL];

KretschmannScalar := 
 KretschmannScalar = 
  Simplify@
   Sum[RiemannCurvatureTensorLLLL[[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \
    \[Delta]]] RiemannCurvatureTensorUUUU[[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \
     \[Delta]]], {\[Alpha], dim}, {\[Beta], dim}, {\[Gamma], 
      dim}, {\[Delta], dim}];

WeylCurvatureTensorLLLL := 
 WeylCurvatureTensorLLLL = 
  Simplify@
   Array[If[dim > 3, 
    RiemannCurvatureTensorLLLL[[#1, #2, #3, #4]] - 
     1/(
      dim - 2) (MetricTensorLL[[#1, #3]] \
       RiemannCurvatureTensorLL[[#4, #2]] + 
        MetricTensorLL[[#2, #4]] RiemannCurvatureTensorLL[[#3, \
         #1]] - MetricTensorLL[[#1, #4]] RiemannCurvatureTensorLL[[#3, #2]] - MetricTensorLL[[#2, #3]] RiemannCurvatureTensorLL[[#4, \
          #1]]) + ScalarCurvature/((dim - 1) (dim - 2)) (MetricTensorLL[[#1, #3]] MetricTensorLL[[#4, #2]] - 
           MetricTensorLL[[#1, #4]] MetricTensorLL[[#3, #2]]), 
            0] &, {dim, dim, dim, dim}];

EinsteinTensor := 
 EinsteinTensor = 
  Simplify[
   RiemannCurvatureTensorLL - 1/2 MetricTensorLL ScalarCurvature];

ConformallyFlatSpaceQ := 
 ConformallyFlatSpaceQ = 
  Simplify[Equal[Sequence @@ Flatten@WeylCurvatureTensorLLLL, 0]];

MaximallySymmetricSpaceQ := 
 MaximallySymmetricSpaceQ = 
  Simplify[
   And @@ Flatten@
    Map[# == 0 &, 
     RiemannCurvatureTensorLLLL - 
      Array[ScalarCurvature/(
       dim (dim - 
        1)) (MetricTensorLL[[#1, #3]] MetricTensorLL[[#2, #4]] -
          MetricTensorLL[[#1, #4]] MetricTensorLL[[#2, #3]]) &, \
           {dim, dim, dim, dim}], {4}]];
```

It is hopefully self-explanatory.

In this particular example I am using the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). The first line declares `Rs`, the Schwarzschild radius, to be a constant. We then define the coordinates of the manifold, in this case, $t,r,\theta,\phi$. After that, we input the components of the metric tensor, with its indices lowered (as indicated by the `LL` tag, meaning "lower-lower").

The rest of tensors are calculated by MMA. For example, `ChristoffelSymbolsULL` are the components of the Christoffel symbols, with one upper and two lower indices. Similarly, `ChristoffelSymbolsLLL` are the components of the Christoffel symbols with all indices lowered.

The code also computes the Riemann tensor, the Weyl tensor, and several scalars (Ricci and Kretschmann). Finally, there is a check for whether the manifold is conformally flat and/or maximally symmetric.

To compute covariant derivatives, you can use the known value of the Christoffel symbols, or the expression

```
Sum[1/Sqrt[Det[MetricTensorLL]] D[Sqrt[Det[MetricTensorLL]] MetricTensorUU[[\[Mu] + 1, \[Nu] + 1]] D[f @@ Coordinates, Coordinates[[\[Nu] + 1]]], Coordinates[[\[Mu] + 1]]], {\[Mu], 0, dim - 1}, {\[Nu], 0, dim - 1}]
```

where `f` is an arbitrary scalar function. For higher rank tensor fields, you'll have to make some small modifications to the code.

Comment: thank you! this seems a lot more than what I need. I understand the initial part of definition of the coordinates and of the metric tensor. But where can I define the two vector fields? Also, how can I compute the covariant derivative?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform In your code, how can I choose one specific Christoffel Symbol from the created list? Is there any way to define a function Christoffel[a,b,c] etc?

Answer (score 10):

There is undocumented functionality in the SymbolicTensors package, which underlies `CoordinateChartData`, `CoordinateTransformData`, and the coordinate-system awareness of `Grad`, etc.  You could add the context to `$ContextPath` save needing to type everywhere, though I won't do that in the example below.

First, you want to define a "patch".  This can be done in various ways, but for a diagonal metric tensor the easiest way is scale factors.  Here I'll use Minkowski in spherical coordinates as my example:

```
vars = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
patch = SymbolicTensors`ScaleFactorGeometryPatch[{-1, 1, r, r Sin[\[Theta]]}, vars];
```

This patch is the equivalent of `CoordinateChartData` for your custom metric.  Take a look at `patch["Properties"]` for some interesting things it will spit out.

Next, we need to define the two vector fields in the tensor language of the package.  I'm just using the `SlotSequence` notation to save myself some typing,  The evaluated form would work just as well for input.  Below, `TangentBasis` is a representation of the coordinated basis for vector fields.  There is a `CotangentBasis` for the space of one-forms.  If you wish to use, e.g., an orthonormal basis, the `TangentBasis` with `TransformedBasis` and supply the change of basis matrix in the second argument.

```
v = SymbolicTensors`Tensor[{vt[##], vr[##], v\[Theta][##], 
     v\[CurlyPhi][##]}, {SymbolicTensors`TangentBasis[{##}]}] & @@ vars

u = SymbolicTensors`Tensor[{ut[##], ur[##], u\[Theta][##], 
     u\[CurlyPhi][##]}, {SymbolicTensors`TangentBasis[{##}]}] & @@ vars
```

Finally, we want to do an actual computation.  For this there is a `CovariantD` which returns $\nabla_b v^a$, using the abstract index notation. `CovariantD` has the same sytnax as `Grad` and friends, and all of these take a patch in the third argument.  (Note that `Grad` returns the raised derivative $\nabla^bv^a$.)  The covariant derivative along a vector fields is simply $u^b\nabla_bv^a$.  Since all differentiation functions in M- add the new slot at the end, this then is simply:

```
SymbolicTensors`CovariantD[v, vars, patch] . u
```

If you don't like the fact u comes at the end, you could write this more verbosely as

```
TensorContract[ 
    TensorProduct[u, SymbolicTensors`CovariantD[v, vars, patch]],
   {1, 3}
]
```

Comment: You & I could have used this functionality back in our grad school days.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Who do you think wrote the package? :)