# Is there a way to add my own coordinate chart?

Tags: customization, vector-calculus

You all may have seen something like this:

```
U = Laplacian[Phi, {r, theta, phi}, "Spherical"]
```

What I want is to add my own Chart with its own coordinates, metric and so on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is not documented, but the functionality does exis, assuming you only want to do all your computations in the given patch.  I have a more detailed answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138831/compute-covariant-derivative-in-mathematica/153744) focusing on how to compute covariant derivatives.  You can the use this patch anywhere a would use a single, named coordinate system, for example:

```
vars = {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
patch = SymbolicTensors`ScaleFactorGeometryPatch[{1, a r, a r Sin[\[Theta]]}, vars];
Laplacian[u @@ vars, vars, patch] // Simplify
```

If you want a non-diagonal metric, you need to use the full tensor language:

```
patch = SymbolicTensors`RiemannianGeometryPatch[
   SymbolicTensors`Tensor[
       {{1, a, 0}, {a, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]}}, 
       {SymbolicTensors`CotangentBasis[vars],  SymbolicTensors`CotangentBasis[vars]}
   ], 
   vars
];
```

If you're just computing scalar Laplacians, this won't matter, but it will automatically compute an orthonormal basis to use if you compute, say, the `Grad` of a scalar or list.  This basis can be extracted using `patch["OrthonormalBasis"]`.  All properties can be extracted using `patch["Properties"]`.