# Vector calculus in generalised orthogonal frame of reference

Tags: vector-calculus

I want to write Navier-Stokes equations in generalised orthogonal frame of reference in Mathematica. I therefore want to expand gradient and other vector calculus operations using metric factors such that `Grad[ϕ[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}]` expands as

$$\nabla \phi = \frac{1}{h_1} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1} \mathbf i_1 +  \frac{1}{h_2} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_2} \mathbf i_2  + \frac{1}{h_3} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_3} \mathbf i_3,$$

where `h1`, `h2` and `h3` are maintained in the Mathematica's output so I can express the equations, after simplifying the expansions, in a desired reference frame. I do not really know how to make Mathematica use the metrics `h`.

Could you provide me with some methodology for this?

Comment: _Mathematica_ already supports several basis, see [Grad](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html) for examples.

Comment: That's true but doesn't really do the trick. I want to have a general expression such that I can define my own, body-fitted, reference frames through the metrics.

Comment: Why do you not define your own Gradient, Laplacian.... E.g.` grad= {1/h1 D[#,x1], 1/h2 D[#,x2],1/h3 D[#,x3]}&`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's a fairly obvious solution that did not cross my mind. Works well!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to define your own coordinate chart according to [Is there a way to add my own coordinate chart?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173852/is-there-a-way-to-add-my-own-coordinate-chart)
In your case

```
patch = SymbolicTensors`ScaleFactorGeometryPatch[{h1, h2, h3}, {x1, x2, x3}];
Grad[f[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}, patch]
```

It is important to note that `h1, h2, h3` will be treated as constants unless you define them as functions of coordinates. Also, you may need to specify `$Assumptions = h1 > 0 && h2 > 0 && h3 > 0` to avoid expressions like $\sqrt{h_i^2}$. You can compute Div and Curl the same way by substituting `patch` in place of `chart`.