# Computing Christoffel symbols of the second kind

Tags: tensors, differential-geometry

I want to compute the Christoffel-symbol for a given metric. I am using the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218424/difficulties-on-mathematica-code-to-solve-christoffel-symbols-of-a-particular-me?rq=1), but I am missing something.

The Chrisfoffel-symbol formula is

$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\phantom{\mu}\nu\sigma}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\alpha}\left\{\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\nu}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}+\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}}-\frac{\partial g_{\nu\sigma}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right\}\quad$

The metric is given to be

$g_{\mu \nu} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & r^2+b^2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & (r^2+b^2)\sin^2(\theta) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1
    \end{pmatrix}
$

The provided solution is:

$\Gamma^{1}_{22}=-r$

$\Gamma^{1}_{33}=-r\sin^2(\theta)$

$\Gamma^{2}_{21}=\frac{r}{b^2+r^2}$

$\Gamma^{2}_{33}=-\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$

$\Gamma^{3}_{31}=\frac{r}{b^2+r^2}$

$\Gamma^{3}_{32}=\cot(\theta)$

The code I'm using is

```
xx = {t, x, \[Theta], \[Phi]};

g  = { {1,0,0,0},
{0,r^2+b^2,0,0},
{0,0,(r^2+b^2)Sin[\[Theta]]^2,0},
{0,0,0,-1}};

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];

ChristoffelSymbol[g_, xx_] := 
Block[{n, ig, res}, 
n = 4; ig = InverseMetric[ g]; 
res = Table[(1/2)*Sum[ ig[[i,s]]*(-D[ g[[j,k]], xx[[s]]] + D[ g[[j,s]], xx[[k]]] 
+ D[ g[[s,k]], xx[[j]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
Simplify[ res]
]
```

But I do not get the desired answer.

What am I missing? Besides, I'd like to learn how could I display the answer once I know how to actually get it.

Note I also checked Artes' solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908) but I do not get how to run the code either.

---

**EDIT**

After playing around a bit with the Christoffel symbols (which is much more fun when you use Mathematica ;)) I've realized of several features:

1. If the metric is diagonal then the only way to get a non-zero Christoffel symbol is when any of the indices appears **at least** twice.
2. If the metric is diagonal we cannot have any index appearing three times yielding a non-trivial Christoffel symbol. The reason is because $g_{rr}$ is independent of $r$, $g_{\theta \theta}$ is independent of $\theta$, $g_{\phi \phi}$ is independent of $\phi$ and $g_{tt}$ is independent of $t$, which implies $\partial_{\mu} g_{\nu \rho}=0$ when $\mu=\nu=\rho$
3. Based on 1. and 2. we conclude that (when the metric is diagonal) **all non-trivial Christoffel symbols must show repeated indices exactly twice**.

Comment: Many statements in this code seem incosistent: for instance, there is an expression `inversemetric` that involves an expression `metric`, but `metric` is undefined and should probably be `g`, just above. Further, in the body of `ChristoffelSymbol` there is reference to a _function_ called `InverseMetric` (note the capitalization and the arguments in hard brackets) but this function is also undefined. It should maybe just be `inversemetric`...?

Comment: It seems you haven't checked [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908) carefully. There is no `metric` defined, `g` stands for the metric.

Comment: This question is based on a basic misunderstanding of the code here: [How to calculate scalar curvature Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908)

Comment: @Artes absolutely, that's a typo of mine. Actually in my first try I used the code in your answer (which is a gem), labelling the metric g. My issue was in how to call out the function once defined (sorry, my programming skills are really really basic XD). Now I learned how; we first label the function ``sol = ChristoffelSymbol[g, xx]`` and then call out a specific solution, for instance ``sol[[1, 2, 2]]``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you provided is a definition for a function to compute the Christoffel symbol (and `Inverse` to compute the inverse metric, I do not know "InverseMetric")

```
ChristoffelSymbol[g_, xx_] := 
 Block[{n, ig, res}, n = Length[xx]; ig = Inverse[g];
  res = Table[(1/2)*
     Sum[ig[[i, s]]*(-D[g[[j, k]], xx[[s]]] + D[g[[j, s]], xx[[k]]] + 
         D[g[[s, k]], xx[[j]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k,
      1, n}];
  Simplify[res]]
```

Then you have to define coordinates `xx` and the compontents  `metric`  **with respect to the coordinate basis**.

```
(* The coordinates *)
xx = {r, \[Theta], \[Phi], t};

(* The metric *)
g = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, r^2 + b^2, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, (r^2 + b^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};

(* The Christoffel *)
sol = ChristoffelSymbol[g, xx] (* This calls the function! *);

sol[[1, 2, 2]]
(* -r *)

sol[[1, 3, 3]]
(* -r Sin[\[Theta]]^2 *)

sol[[2, 2, 1]]
(* r/(b^2 + r^2) *)

sol[[2, 3, 3]]
(* -Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]] *)

sol[[3, 3, 1]]
(* r/(b^2 + r^2) *)

sol[[3, 3, 2]]
(* Cot[\[Theta]] *)
```

Edited the answer with the correct coordinates.

Note that you get some coefficients "twice" since the Christoffel symbols are symmetric.

```
Union@Flatten@With[{n = Length[xx]}, Table[sol[[i, j, k]] == sol[[i, k, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]]
(* {True} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Note there's something missing in your code. Please see the provided solution above; you do not get 4 of the 6 Christoffel symbols and you get $\cot(\theta)$ twice.

Comment: Natas I got it thanks! Just one last question: does the code ``Union@Flatten@With[{n = Length[xx]}, Table[sol[[i, j, k]] == sol[[i, k, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]]
(* {True} *)`` simply verify that the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in their lower indices? If yes, how does it work? I've tried ``sol[[3,3,1]]==sol[3,1,3]`` expecting a true as an output but did not work.

Comment: Indeed it does simply verify that the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in the lower indices. `sol[[3,3,1]]==sol[[3,1,3]]` should work (double brackets are used for indexing in Mathematica). The `@` is simply is shorthand for `Prefix` and `f[x] == f@x`. In the code you quoted I check this (inefficiently) for all indices which gives a nested list of `True` which is flattened with `Flatten` and then the duplicates are removed with `Union`. Had there been a case in which the symmetry condition had been violated it would give `{False, True}`.