# Christoffel symbol of 2nd kind

Tags: tensors

How to calculate Christoffel symbol of 2nd kind for a given metric tensor in Mathematica ? I tried a few programming but I'm not getting desired output .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate scalar curvature, Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathe). You may also see [Computing Christoffel symbols of the second kind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224280/27951). A quick search of the site will give you even more results.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.