# How do I extract the component from an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I'm embarrassed that I don't even know the language for what I'm asking. The result of an operation I'm performing is:
$$expression=-dt^2 \left(c + a t\right)^2$$
$dt$ is basically an infinitesimal in a metric and I want to extract everything else. That is, I'm trying to construct a metric tensor from the components of a metric formula. I want a function, f, such that$$f[expression]=-\left(c + a t\right)^2$$
In Mathematica, for what function am I looking?

Comment: $dt$ is not an infinitesimal, but rather a linear one-form, i.e., physisicts use to write $dt^2$ instead of $dt \otimes dt$ namely a bilinear form.

Comment: $g(\partial t, \partial t)= g_{tt}\;$-that's all.

Comment: I don't understand that notation. Could you try that in the 'Input' form, please.

Comment: You should think about your goal once more, if `expression` is a metric tensor, then the last comment explains how to get the coefficient at $dt \otimes dt$ otherwise your question is not well posed.  Nonetheless a slightly more detailed discussion one can find here [How to calculate scalar curvature, Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathe/8908#8908).  $\partial t $ is a normalized vector in a tangent  vector space to a manifold.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. They're valuable. My issue is not so much with your answer as the fact that I can't translate what you said into Mathematica. If you'd be so kind as to express your thoughts in the 'Input' form of Mathematica, then I could reproduce it and dissect it to understand your meaning.

Comment: While $dt(\partial t)=1 $, then $dt \otimes dt$ is a tensor product of two one-forms $dt$. Take a closer  look at the link above or examine a more sophisticated package for tensor calculus in general relativity.

Comment: `Coefficient[Dt[t]^2 (c + a t)^2, Dt[t]^2]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.

```
dssq = -dt^2 (c + a t)^2

Coefficient[dssq, dt^2]
(* -(a t + c)^2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the word for which I was looking: Coefficient.

Comment: You're welcome.  We all have those days sometimes.

Comment: The line element is `ds^2`, not ds.