# Numbered symbols

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I work with an exterior algebra over $R^n$. I have the basis $\{1,\omega_i\}_{i=1}^n$ in this algebra, and my differential operator is defined as

$$d\omega_k=\sum_{i>j>0,i+j=k} (i-j)w_i\wedge w_j.$$

As you see, my sum depends directly on the indexes of the elements of the basis. I surely can define the wedge and the differential operator in *Mathematica*, and they will calculate the derivative for any polynome I want. My problem is to find a good way to describe the elements of the basis, which will permit me use these formulas easily. It can not be just the integers $1, .. n$ for every element $\omega_1, .. \omega_n$, because *Mathematica* will multiply them as normal numbers, not treating them as elements of the exterior algebra; it cannot be just symbols such as `w1`, `w2`, ... because I cannot easily extract the numbers from them to calculate the derivatives (or I just don't know how).

I tried to represent them with `{1}`, `{2}`, and so on. I also used noncommutative multiplication with additional relations as the exterior multiplication. Example of what my notebook can calculate:

```
In[30]:= d[{5} ** {4}]
Out[30]= {4} ** {3} ** {2} + 2 {5} ** {3} ** {1}
```

That's nice. I defined multiplication and differentiation without problems, except for one small thing -- multiplying by a scalar. For example, consider the expression $2\omega_4+\omega_5$. In this notation it appears as `2 {4} + {5}`. Mathematica proceeds to `{8} + {5}` and then to `{13}`, which is completely wrong.

```
In[31]:= 2 {4} + {5}
Out[31]= {13}
```

This only happens when working with dimension 1. For higher grades everything's fine because *Mathematica*'s multiplication doesn't misbehave when working with non-commutative elements:

```
In[32]:= 2 {4} ** {3} + 6 {5} ** {2}
Out[32]= 2 {4} ** {3} + 6 {5} ** {2}

In[33]:= (2 {4} ** {3} + 6 {5} ** {2}) ** {3}
Out[33]= -6 {5} ** {3} ** {2}
```

But this is still not what I want -- lower dimensions are important to me, so my question is: how do I represent the basis elements without these problems? I can try to partially clear `Times`, but I don't think this is best way, as the multiplication of lists may be vital later in the code.

Comment: Why not w@1 ... w@n ?

Comment: The answer by helen to [Differential geometry add-ons for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2620/245) describes how *Atlas 2* can handle this - but that's a commercial product and I can understand if you want to build your own version. However, maybe you can find some useful ideas in that link.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks a lot, this works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!. And please,change your userid to something easier to remember!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do

```
lst = w /@ Range[10]
(*{w[1], w[2], w[3], w[4], w[5], w[6], w[7], w[8], w[9], w[10]}*)
```

You can extract indices like this

```
lst /. w[n_] :> n
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

(this works on each element, so eg `w[3] /. w[n_] :> n` evaluates to `3` and so on).