# Linearized Einstein Equations with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, packages, tensors, code-request

I need to compute the linearised Einstein Equations around a fixed metric  $g_{\mu \nu}$ which is not the flat metric.

Someone knows any *Mathematica* package or a review that can help me?

Comment: I recommend this one [Efficient tensor computer algebra for Mathematica](http://www.xact.es/). Here is a related question [Differential geometry add-ons for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/differential-geometry-add-ons-for-mathematica). You could start with this answer [How to calculate scalar curvature Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908) and then exploit new tensor capabilities in `Mathematica 9`.

Comment: @Artes You could make that into an answer (reduce unanswered count).  There's not much more to say here.

Answer (score 7):

As @Artes mentions in his comment, this can be done with [xAct](http://xact.es/), in particular with its [xPert package](http://xact.es/xPert/). After installing it, we may load it with

```
<< xAct`xPert`
```

We first need to set up some variables:

```
(* Define a 4-dimensional manifold. *)
DefManifold[M, 4, IndexRange[a, l]]

(* Define a (Lorentzian) metric and its associated curvature tensors. *)
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"]

(* Define metric perturbations, with H being the fluctuation of the metric. *)
DefMetricPerturbation[metric, H, ϵ]
```

The linearized Einstein tensor can then be computed by perturbing the non-linear Einstein tensor, and subsequently expanding the perturbation:

```
linearEinstein = ExpandPerturbation @ Perturbation[ EinsteinCD[-a, -b] ]
```

> $\tfrac{1}{2} (- \nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}H^{1c}{}_{c} - \nabla_{a}\nabla_{c}H^{1c}{}_{b} + \nabla_{a}\nabla^{c}H^{1}{}_{bc}) + \tfrac{1}{2} (\nabla_{c}\nabla_{a}H^{1c}{}_{b} + \nabla_{c}\nabla_{b}H^{1c}{}_{a} - \nabla_{c}\nabla^{c}H^{1}{}_{ba})$
>   $ + \tfrac{1}{2} (- H^{1}{}_{ab} R - g_{ab} (- H^{1cd} R_{cd} + g^{cd} (\tfrac{1}{2} (- \nabla_{c}\nabla_{d}H^{1e}{}_{e} - \nabla_{c}\nabla_{e}H^{1e}{}_{d} + \nabla_{c}\nabla^{e}H^{1}{}_{de})$
>   $ + \tfrac{1}{2} (\nabla_{e}\nabla_{c}H^{1e}{}_{d} + \nabla_{e}\nabla_{d}H^{1e}{}_{c} - \nabla_{e}\nabla^{e}H^{1}{}_{dc}))))$

We can clean this up a bit as follows:

```
linearEinstein // ContractMetric // ToCanonical
```

> $\tfrac{1}{2} H^{1cd} g_{ab} R_{cd} -  \tfrac{1}{2} H^{1}{}_{ab} R -  \tfrac{1}{2} \nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}H^{1c}{}_{c} + \tfrac{1}{2} \nabla_{c}\nabla_{a}H^{1}{}_{b}{}^{c} + \tfrac{1}{2} \nabla_{c}\nabla_{b}H^{1}{}_{a}{}^{c} -  \tfrac{1}{2} \nabla_{c}\nabla^{c}H^{1}{}_{ab} -  \tfrac{1}{2} g_{ab} \nabla_{d}\nabla_{c}H^{1cd} + \tfrac{1}{2} g_{ab} \nabla_{d}\nabla^{d}H^{1c}{}_{c}$

If you know the values of the background curvature tensors, you could plug them in, or alternatively, compute them from the background metric with the [xCoba package](http://xact.es/xCoba/index.html).

Comment: +1. Maybe you could incorporate you answer also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48263/5478)? The only difference is to put `g = {-1,1,1,1}`, right?