# Linearised Einstein equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, packages, code-request

I need to compute the linearised Einstein Equations around a fixed metric

$$g_{μν}=\text{Minkowski metric} + h_{μν}$$

which is not the flat metric.

Does anyone know a *Mathematica* package or a review paper that can help me?

Comment: You can start there: [Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8895/5478)

Comment: Closely related: [**35598**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35598/5478). If I understand correctly the only difference is to use Minkowski metric instead of symbolic one.