# Computing Gaussian curvature

Tags: code-request, differential-geometry

Can Gaussian curvature $K$ be computed from `WolframAlpha` or any other available *Mathematica* program? Please indicate the program or its reference.

If input parametrization is given as Gaussian curvature of

`X[u,v] = {Cos[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u]}`

it simply outputs an assembly of three individual Cartesian prismatic Monge 3D (u,v) plots and their plotted `K` but does not refer to meridians and parallels of a single unit sphere surface.

Comment: There are new in (_v. 10_) `FrenetSerretSystem` and `ArcCurvature` but they compute curvature of curves only. See e.g. this [Finding unit tangent...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/56469#56469). In general on a manifold (e.g. surface) you can compute Gauss curvature calculating Christoffel Symbols see e.g. [How to calculate Ricci curvature and Christoffel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Differential geometry add-ons for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/differential-geometry-add-ons-for-mathematica)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note this parametric surface of  unit sphere (S^2) should have constant Gaussian curvature: 1.

Surface:

```
x[u_, v_] := {Cos[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u]}
```

First fundamental form:

```
fff = FullSimplify[With[{p1 = D[x[a, b], a], p2 = D[x[a, b], b]},
   {p1.p1, p1.p2, p2.p2}]];
```

Second fundamental form:

```
nm = FullSimplify[Cross[D[x[a, b], a], D[x[a, b], b]]];
unm = FullSimplify[nm/Sqrt[nm.nm]];
sec = {D[x[a, b], {a, 2}], Derivative[1, 1][x][a, b], 
  D[x[a, b], {b, 2}]};
sff = FullSimplify[#.unm & /@ sec];
```

Gaussian Curvature:

```
de[{e_, f_, g_}] = e g - f^2
FullSimplify[de[#1]/de[#2] & @@ {sff, fff}]
```

yields 1

The mean curvature:

```
FullSimplify[(sff Reverse[fff]).{1, -2, 1}/(2 de[fff])]
```

yields: Sqrt[Cos[a]^2] Sec[a], which is clearly 1 as required.

i.e. K=1, H=1, $\kappa1 =1,\kappa2=1$

Simplifications can be challenging...others will have better approaches

Comment: Dear @ ubpdqn. Thanks for understanding Gauss.

Comment: @eldo "Die Mathematik ist die Königin der Wissenschaften..."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere

Comment: @ubpdqn: Jawohl ...ihre Schönheit verdoppelt mit Mathematica.

Comment: @Narasimham I just posted the answer to illustrate a way to calculate Gaussian curvature for smooth surfaces (manifolds) using first and second fundamental forms. Varying x[u,v] should work for other surfaces, acknowledging issues of singular points, ugly expressions from limitations of simplifications.

Comment: @ubpdqn: When K result is in terms of (a,b) instead of (u,v).. FullSimplify[{de[#1]/de[#2] & @@ {sff, fff}}];
Plot3D[%, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]  works OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

**Definition**

```
GaussCurvature[f_] :=
  With[{dfu = D[f, u], dfv = D[f, v]},
     Simplify[(Det[{D[dfu, u], dfu, dfv}] Det[{D[dfv, v], dfu, dfv}] -
     Det[{D[f, u, v], dfu, dfv}]^2) / (dfu.dfu  dfv.dfv - (dfu.dfv)^2)^2]];
```

**Sphere**

As @ ubpdqn already remarked

```
GaussCurvature[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}]
```

> 1

**Ellipsoid**

```
ellipsoid = {2 Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]};

cur = GaussCurvature[ellipsoid]
```

[image]

```
plo =
 Plot3D[cur, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

```
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plo, PlotRange]]
```

> {0.25, 4.}

```
ParametricPlot3D[ellipsoid, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> False,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
   ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[cur, range]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

**Torus**

```
torus = {(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]};

cur = GaussCurvature[torus]
```

[image]

```
plo =
 Plot3D[cur, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

```
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plo, PlotRange]]
```

> {-1., 0.333333}

```
par =
  ParametricPlot3D[
   torus, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   Mesh -> False,
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[cur, range]]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   PlotPoints -> 70];

bar =
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", range}, Automatic];

Row[{par, bar}]
```

[image]

**Moebius with gaussian mesh lines**

```
f = {Cos[v] (3 + u Cos[v/2]), Sin[v] (3 + u Cos[v/2]), u Sin[v/2]};
cur = GaussCurvature[f];

ParametricPlot3D[f, {u, -1.5, 1.5}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 Boxed -> False,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Mesh -> 12,
 PlotPoints -> 120,
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Rescale[cur, {-0.04, -0.02}]],
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
   ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[cur, {-0.04, -0.02}]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

**Comparison with Mean Curvature**

A must-read about those jolly times:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain

```
sincos = {u, v, Sin[u] Cos[v]};
cur = GaussCurvature[sincos];
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plo, PlotRange]];

p1 =
 ParametricPlot3D[sincos, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  Mesh -> 6,
  PlotLabel -> Style["Gaussian Curvature\n", 16, Bold],
  PlotPoints -> 120,
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Rescale[cur, range]],
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[cur, range]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

MeanCurvature[f_] :=
  With[{du = D[f, u], dv = D[f, v]},
      Simplify[(Det[{D[du, u], du, dv}] * dv.dv -
       2 Det[{D[f, u, v], du, dv}] * du.dv + Det[{D[dv, v], du, dv}] * du.du) /
           (2 Simplify[(du.du*dv.dv - (du.dv)^2)]^(3/2))]];

cur = MeanCurvature[sincos];
plo = Plot3D[cur, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}];
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plo, PlotRange]];

p2 =
 ParametricPlot3D[sincos, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  Mesh -> 6,
  PlotLabel -> Style["Mean Curvature\n", 16, Bold],
  PlotPoints -> 120,
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Rescale[cur, range]],
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[cur, range]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

Row[{p1, p2, BarLegend[{"Rainbow", range}, LegendMarkerSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

**Update for space curves**

```
curvature[f_] :=
 With[{d1 = D[f, u], d2 = D[f, {u, 2}]},
  Norm[Cross[d1, d2]] / Norm[d1]^3 // Simplify]

loxodromes[a_, b_] :=
 {
   2 a E^(b u) Cos[u],
   2 a E^(b u) Sin[u],
   a^2 E^(2 b u) - 1
   } / (1 + a^2 E^(2 b u))

cur = curvature[loxodromes[1, 0.1]];

plo = Plot[cur, {u, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plo, PlotRange]];

Show[

 ParametricPlot3D[loxodromes[1, 0.1], {u, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[cur, range]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]],

 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[]}],

 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**A nice novel about Gauss**

[image]

Comment: @eldo very nice and thank you for book recommendation...will add to my wish list

Comment: @eldo congratulations on 10K!

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you very much for noticing :)

Answer (score 5):

Another expression using `Cross`

```
gaussianCurvature[r_, {u_, v_}] := 
 Module[{n, ru = D[r, u], rv = D[r, v], ruv = D[r, u, v]},
  n = Cross[ru, rv];
  ((D[ru, u].n) (D[rv, v].n) - (ruv.n)^2)/(n.n)^2 // Simplify
]
```

Examples

```
gaussianCurvature[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, v}]
```

> `1`

Answer (score 3):

#### Curvatures of implicitly defined surfaces

**1. Gaussian curvature**

Based upon burnout's answer to this question:

[How to speed up estimation of Mean and Gaussian curvatures on triangular meshes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117884/how-to-speed-up-estimation-of-mean-and-gaussian-curvatures-on-triangular-meshes)

we can compute the Gaussian curvature of implicitly defined surfaces as follows:

```
fun = -x^2 + x^4 - y^2 + y^4 - z^2 + z^4;

d1 = D[fun, {{x, y, z}}] // Simplify;
d2 = D[fun, {{x, y, z}, 2}] // Simplify;

gauss[x_, y_, z_] =
  Simplify[((d1 . LinearSolve[d2, d1]) Det[d2]) / (# . # & [d1])^2];

Legended[
 ContourPlot3D[fun == -1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[gauss[x, y, z], {-3, 3}]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Mesh -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 70],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-3.1, 3.1}}, Automatic]]
```

[image]

The scaling of {-3, 3} was inserted manually, because I didn't find a way to automate this. But this doesn't take too long. Start with {-1, 1} and go up or down.

**2. Mean curvature**

The same link also provides a formula for Mean curvature:

```
fun = -x^2 + x^4 - y^2 + y^4 - z^2 + z^4;

d1 = D[fun, {{x, y, z}}] // Simplify;
d2 = D[fun, {{x, y, z}, 2}] // Simplify;

mcur[x_, y_, z_] =
  Simplify[(d1 . d2 . d1 - Tr[d2] (# . # &[d1])) / (2 (# . # & [d1])^(3/2))];

Legended[
 ContourPlot3D[fun == -1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[Abs @ mcur[x, y, z], {0, 3}]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Mesh -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 70],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 3.1}}, Automatic]]
```

[image]

**3. Mesh lines**

The two curvature functions can also be applied to mesh lines:

```
fun = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 + 3 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2);

d1 = D[fun, {{x, y, z}}] // Simplify;
d2 = D[fun, {{x, y, z}, 2}] // Simplify;

mcur[x_, y_, z_] = 
 Simplify[(d1 . d2 . d1 - 
     Tr[d2] (# . # & [d1])) / (2 (# . # &[d1])^(3/2))];


Legended[
 ContourPlot3D[fun == 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[Abs @ mcur[x, y, z], {0, 1}]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Mesh -> 12,
  MeshFunctions -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Rescale[Abs @ mcur[x, y, z], {0, 1}]],
  PlotPoints -> 70],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1.1}}, Automatic]]
```

[image]

Comment: In the image transition of double curvature K depicted beautifully. Base faces ( of fattened tetrahedron )  transition with negative K from base towards sides and  among side  faces with positive K . Perhaps in each corner octant $(0,1)$ it would be clearer.