# Curvature of a Klein bottle

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

**1. Problem statement**

An old answer of mine:
[Computing Gaussian curvature](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61409/computing-gaussian-curvature/61444#61444) shows how to color parametric curves
and surfaces according to their curvature. However, the methods used there will fail for non-differentiable and very complicated functions. A workaround, not perfect, but the only one I know, is to color such surfaces according to their polygon sizes. Polygon areas decrease in zones of high curvature. I know how to use this "area method" in my `Blender/Python` application, but don't know how to transfer it to `Mathematica`.

**2. Curvature of a Torus (formula method)**

```
GaussianCurvature[f_] :=
 With[{dfu = D[f, u], dfv = D[f, v]}, 
  Simplify[(Det[{D[dfu, u], dfu, dfv}] * Det[{D[dfv, v], dfu, dfv}] - 
      Det[{D[f, u, v], dfu, dfv}]^2) / (dfu.dfu * dfv.dfv - (dfu.dfv)^2)^2]]

torus = {(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]};

curvature = GaussianCurvature[torus]
```

Cos[v] / (2 + Cos[v])

```
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[Plot3D[curvature, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}], PlotRange]]
```

{-1., 0.333333}

```
Legended[
 ParametricPlot3D[torus, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunction ->
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v},ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[curvature, range]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  Mesh -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 70],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", range}, Automatic]]
```

[image]

**3. Curvature of a Torus with Blender/Python (area method)**

The Blender 3.6.5 Python API has a method, `calc_area()` which returns a list of polygon sizes (basically with one line of code):

`p.list = [f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces]`

("Faces" are rectangular polygons defined by 4 points). A rescaled list of these sizes is then used to index the color table and color the polygons. We can see that the `Blender` result is very similar to the above `Mathematica` plot:

[image]

**4. The Klein bottle**

```
KleinBottle[u_, v_] :=
 Module[{a, b, c, x, y, z},
  a = 6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u]);
  b = 16 Sin[u];
  c = 5 (1 - Cos[u]/2);
  x = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, a + c Cos[v + Pi], a + c Cos[u] Cos[v]];
  y = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, b, b + c Sin[u] Cos[v]];
  z = c Sin[v];
  {x, y, z}]

klein =
 ParametricPlot3D[
  KleinBottle[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

Because it is not possible to apply the curvature formula to this complicated surface, I show how it would look like in `Blender` using the "polygon area method" with a logarithmic scale and `TemperatureMap` imported from `Mathematica`:

[image]

**5. Question**

I know how to extract the polygons, f.e. the first polygon of the Klein bottle:

```
Cases[Normal[klein], _Polygon, Infinity][[1]] // PolygonCoordinates
```

{{8.80683, 0.984612, 0.133244}, {9.10008, 1.96794, 2.67745*10^-7}, {9.08591, 1.96642, 0.267239}}

But I don't know how to proceed from there to calculate the polygon sizes and color the bottle similar to the last screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps `Graphics`Mesh`MeshGaussianCurvature` is the function you are looking for. Unfortunately I couldn't find more detailed info

Comment: Here a link [How to speed up estimation of Mean and Gaussian curvatures on triangular meshes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117884/how-to-speed-up-estimation-of-mean-and-gaussian-curvatures-on-triangular-meshes) which might be of interest .

Comment: Thank you, Ulrich, I will need some time to explore the solutions of your interesting link. Hopefully, someone will find an easier way.

Comment: `Cases` does not seems to extract all polygons of `klein` - there are holes in the figure, if I use it in `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here one way to create a ParametricPlot3D of the Klein bottle with curvature dependent coloring:

First I take a smooth definition found on `Wikipedia`

```
kleinFlasche[u_, v_] := Block[{b = 2, h = 6, r = 2 - Cos[u]},
x = b (1 - Sin[u]) Cos[u] + r Cos[v] (2 Exp[-(u/2 - Pi)^2] - 1);
y = r Sin[v];
z = h Sin[u] + 1/2 r Sin[u] Cos[v] Exp[-(u - 3 Pi/2)^2];
{x, y, z}
]
```

curvature (Thanks to @eldo ;-) )

```
GaussCurvature[f_] := 
With[{dfu = D[f, u],dfv = D[f,v]}, 
(Det[{D[dfu, u], dfu, dfv}] Det[{D[dfv, v], dfu, dfv}] - 
Det[{D[f, u, v], dfu, dfv}]^2)
/(dfu . dfu dfv . dfv - (dfu . dfv)^2)^2] ;
```

Plot of the bottle

```
ParametricPlot3D[kleinFlasche[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ColorFunction ->Function[{x, y, z, u,v},Evaluate[Hue[GaussCurvature[kleinFlasche[u, v]]]]], Mesh -> False,PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 - It not only helps, but answers the question, thank you so much.

Comment: You' re welcome. Interesting question , I learned a lot

Answer (score 1):

As a footnote to Ulrich Neumann's answer I would like to show how the bottle looks like with `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]`

```
curvature = GaussCurvature[kleinFlasche[u, v]];
```

The resulting function is too long to be shown here.

```
range =
 Last[PlotRange /. 
   AbsoluteOptions[Plot3D[curvature, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}], PlotRange]]
```

{-0.580809, 0.504683}

```
Legended[
 ParametricPlot3D[kleinFlasche[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunction ->
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[curvature, range]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  Mesh -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 70],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", range}, Automatic]]
```

The output nicely shows the jump from positive to negative curvature
at the top of the bottle.

[image]

Comment: Very  nice coloring!

Answer (score 0):

The two cases of the embeddes surfaces have the line elements

```
  Collect[(# . # &)[Assuming[u < \[Pi],Simplify[
   du D[KleinBottle[u, v], u] + dv D[KleinBottle[u, v], v]]]] // 
FullSimplify // TrigReduce, {du, dv}] // Simplify
```

$$\frac{25}{16} \left(\text{du}^2 (\cos (2 (u-v))+\cos (2 (u+v))-4 \cos (u+2 v)-4 \cos (u-2 v)-8 \cos (u)+8 \cos (2 v)+10)-4 \text{du} \text{dv} \sin (u) (\cos (u)-2) \sin (2 v)+4 \text{dv}^2 (\cos (u)-2)^2\right)$$

```
Collect[(# . # &)[
 Assuming[2 \[Pi] > u > \[Pi], 
  Simplify[
   du D[KleinBottle[u, v], u] + dv D[KleinBottle[u, v], v]]]] // 
FullSimplify // TrigReduce, {du, dv}] // Simplify
```

$$\frac{25}{32} \left(8 \text{du}^2 \sin ^2(u) \sin ^2(v)-8 \text{du} \text{dv} \sin (u) (\cos (u)-2) \sin (2 v)+8 \text{dv}^2 (\cos (u)-2)^2\right)$$

Its not too difficult to obtain the curvature.