# Gaussian curvature of a point cloud surface

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, curvature

Having a set of triplets like `dsurf={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}` whose interpolation defines an open surface (as shown by `ListPlot3D`), is there a direct way to obtain the Gaussian curvature of the surface also as a discrete function, meaning `{{x1,y1,Gcur1},{x2,y2,Gcur2},...}` ?

One way out can be to interpolate the surface and then to use `ResourceFunction["GaussianCurvature"]`, but I guess the interpolation will incur in some inaccuracy and more than that - we don't need a continuous function but just the curvature at the specific points.

---

EDIT: To avoid interpolation I think of using the formula

$$
\begin{align}
K_G=\frac{F_{xx}F_{yy}-F_{xy}^2}{\left(1+F_x^2+F_y^2\right)^2},
\end{align}
$$

if $z=F(x,y)$, taking the derivatives with some kind of finite difference method or the like. The question is more about what is the best way to do that.

Moreover, if we try to interpolate it cannot be done beyond 1st order because it is on an unstructured grid. Some sample data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkn5m7lYBqlk4H5Pc6ZRXxaJesytbDkW/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Err... you do need the continuous function. A point cloud has no curvature. The choice of interpolation influences the curvature too - e.g order 0 and 1 has no curvature except infinite curvature at the seams, while higher orders have different curvatures.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09972.pdf) suggests a possible method. `nf = Nearest[dsurf];` then find the neighborhood points in some radius $\varepsilon > 0$ i.e `nf[dsurf, p, {All, ε}]`. Then use `{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[Covariance[pts]];` to get the principal components vectors and eigenvalues for that neighborhood.  According to the paper, you fit a quadratic hypersurface to the points on p9. The coefficients $a$ then go in a Hessian matrix, and the determinant of this gives an approximation of the Gaussian curvature. You also need to try out multiple ε to ensure it's stable

Comment: ^ but all that seems rather complicated. So it would be better if you provided any sample data that was causing you interpolation problems, so we can fix that and then calculate the curvature on the interpolation. Also, you can always select points for interpolation within a neighborhood / radius of the candidate point using `Nearest` as above, and this might help if there are too many points in the whole point set.

Comment: @flinty Thank you. Please see edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have adopted a method like the one in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09972.pdf), at least my best effort to implement it. We disregard other dimensions and just focus on the 3D point cloud as a surface, which is mostly intuitive.

It is sensitive to noise and the choice of radius, so you may need to pick a suitable radius for the neighborhood (the sphere in the diagram)

```
SeedRandom[1];
(* Our underlying surface *)
f[x_, y_] := 1 + x^2 + 0.5 y^3;
n = 5000;
(* A point cloud drawn from our surface, but with a tiny bit of noise added *)
noise = RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.01], n];
pts = (Append[#, (f @@ #)] & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]) + noise;

(* The point to test *)
testPoint = pts[[30]];

(* Compute the NearestFunction of the point cloud, so we can make radius queries *)
nf = Nearest[pts];

(* The neighbourhood of testPoint to use to estimate the GC *)
radius = 0.3;
neighborhood = nf[testPoint, {All, radius}];

(** Find the principal components, i.e eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. We must center the neighborhood on the test point before taking the covariance. **)
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[Covariance[neighborhood - Threaded[testPoint]]];
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[.5], Sphere[testPoint, radius]},
  {Blue, Opacity[1], PointSize[Large], Point@neighborhood},
  {Gray, PointSize[.0075], Point@pts},
  {Red, Opacity[1], PointSize[.025], Point@testPoint},
  {Arrow[{testPoint, testPoint + 3 radius evecs[[1]]}],
   Arrow[{testPoint, testPoint + 3 radius evecs[[2]]}],
   Arrow[{testPoint, testPoint + 3 radius evecs[[3]]}]}
  }]

(* Project the neighborhood points onto the the new axes, i.e the principal components *)
projected = evecs . (# - testPoint) & /@ neighborhood;

(* Find the a[i,j] that minimize this cost *) 
cost = Sum[(1/2 Sum[a[i, j] p[[i]] p[[j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}] - 
     p[[3]])^2, {p, projected}];
(* Shove those in a matrix and compute the determinant to get the estimated curvature. *)
estimatedGaussianCurvature = Det[ArrayReshape[
   Values@Last@NMinimize[cost, Variables[cost]]
   , {2, 2}]]
```

[image: Gaussian Curvature of a Point Cloud points neighborhood]

We get an estimated Gaussian curvature of -1.14881.
We can compare this to the true value of the curvature of `f` without noise at the `testPoint` as follows. Credit to @eldo [for this code in his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61444/72682):

```
(* Test if it agrees with the true Gaussian curvature *)
GaussianCurvature[f_] := 
  With[{dfx = D[f, x], 
    dfy = D[f, y]}, (Det[{D[dfx, x], dfx, dfy}] Det[{D[dfy, y], dfx, dfy}] - 
      Det[{D[f, u, v], dfx, dfy}]^2)/(dfx . dfx dfy . dfy - (dfx . dfy)^2)^2];

GaussianCurvature[{x, y, f[x, y]}] /. {x -> testPoint[[1]], y -> testPoint[[2]]}
```

This gives us -1.02857 so the estimate -1.14881 is not too far off.

We can now wrap all this up into functions and tidy some things up:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
NumericMatrixQ = MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &;
objective[a_?NumericMatrixQ, proj_?NumericMatrixQ] := Sum[
  With[{q = Most[p]}, 1/4 (a . q . q - 2 p[[3]])^2], {p, proj}, 
  Method -> "Procedural"]

EstimateSinglePointGaussianCurvature[nf_NearestFunction, point_, radius_] := 
 Module[{evecs, obj}, With[{neigh = nf[point, {All, radius}]},
   If[Length[neigh] < 3, Return[0]];
   evecs = Last@Eigensystem[Covariance[neigh - Threaded[point]]];
   With[{proj = evecs . (# - point) & /@ neigh},
    Return@Det@ArrayReshape[
       Quiet[
        NArgMin[{objective[a, proj], 
          Indexed[a, {1, 2}] == Indexed[a, {2, 1}]}, 
         a ∈ Matrices[{2, 2}, Reals], MaxIterations -> 10, 
         Method -> {"NelderMead", "PostProcess" -> False}]
        , NArgMin::cvmit]
       , {2, 2}]]]]

EstimatePointCloudGaussianCurvature[points_, testpoints_, radius_] := 
 Module[{curvatures},
  With[{nf = Nearest[points]},
    Return[
      ParallelMap[
       EstimateSinglePointGaussianCurvature[nf, #, radius] &, 
       testpoints, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]];
    ];
  ]
```

Here's an example where we estimate the curvature of a point cloud based on the Stanford Bunny:

```
(* Example: estimate the curvature at 10000 points on the StanfordBunny model by sampling 3000 points and smoothing *)
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics@ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}];
pts = RandomPoint[mesh, 10000];
testPoints = RandomSample[pts, 3000];
problemRadius = BoundingRegion[pts, "MinBall"][[2]]/5.;
curvatures = EstimatePointCloudGaussianCurvature[pts, testPoints, problemRadius];
npts = Nearest[testPoints -> "Index"];
(* For each point, compute the average of the curvatures of the 4 nearest test points *)
smoothedCurvatures = Mean[curvatures[[npts[#, 4]]]] & /@ pts;
```

[image: Stanford Bunny]

Comment: Clever answer (+1)! I am a bit unsure about the `Covariance[neighborhood]`-matrix. Usually it is defined with regard to focus  `Mean[neighborhood]` , but here we need a focus `testpoint` I would expect.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann fixed. It's now `Covariance[neighborhood - Threaded[testPoint]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @flinty`s clever solution I would like to introduce an addition which gives slightly better curvature estimations.

In this approach, I try to approximate the "surface" locally(near testpoint) by a quadraticform `z=1/2 {x,y}.A.[x,y}+b.{x,y}` inside the tangentplane of testPoint.

In place of `Covariance[]` matrix we define `kovm = Sum[Outer[Times, dpi, dpi], {dpi,Rest@Map[# - testPoint &, neighborhood]}]/(Length[neighborhood] - 1);` which perhaps better incorporates the reference point `testPoint`.

To compare the results I take one function `fun[tp]` which evaluates curvature from flinty's answer and the curvature from this approach.

```
SeedRandom[ 1];
(*Our underlying surface*)
f[x_, y_] := 1 + x^2 + 0.5 y^3;
n = 5000;
(*A point cloud drawn from our surface,but with a tiny bit of noise \
added*)
noise = RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.01], n];
pts = (Append[#, (f @@ #)] & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]) + 0 noise;
nf = Nearest[pts];
fun =.
fun[tp_] := 
 Block[{testPoint = tp, \[Kappa]Gexakt, \[Kappa]G1 , \[Kappa]G2D, 
   neighborhood, evals, evecs, projected, cost, kovm,
   xyz, A, b, AA, bb, J},
  \[Kappa]Gexakt = (
    D[f[x, y], x, x] D[f[x, y], y, y] - 
     D[f[x, y], x, y]^2)/(1 + D[f[x, y], x ]^2 + 
       D[f[x, y], y ]^2)^2 /. {x -> testPoint[[1]], 
     y -> testPoint[[2]]};
  
  (*The neighbourhood of testPoint to use to estimate the GC*)
  radius = 0.3;
  neighborhood = nf[testPoint, {All, radius}];
   
  {evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[Covariance[neighborhood]];
  
  (*Project the neighborhood points onto the the new axes,
  i.e the principal components*)
  projected = evecs . (# - testPoint) & /@ neighborhood;
  
  (*Find the a[i,j] that minimize this cost*)
  cost = Sum[(1/2 Sum[a[i, j] p[[i]] p[[j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}] - 
       p[[3]])^2, {p, projected}];
  (*Shove those in a matrix and compute the determinant to get the \
estimated curvature.*)
  \[Kappa]G1 = 
   estimatedGaussianCurvature = 
    Det[ArrayReshape[
      Values@Last@NMinimize[cost, Variables[cost]], {2, 2}]];
  
  kovm = Sum[
     Outer[Times, dpi, dpi], {dpi, 
      Rest@Map[# - testPoint &, neighborhood]}]/(Length[
       neighborhood] - 1);
   
  {evals, evecs} = 
   Eigensystem[{Covariance[neighborhood], 
      Covariance[Map[# - testPoint &, neighborhood ]], kovm}[[-1]]] ;
  
   
  xyz = projected ;
  
  A = {{a11, a12}, {a12, a22}};
  b = {b1, b2};
  vars = Join[Variables[A], Variables[b]];
  J = # . # &[
    Map[1/2 #[[{1, 2}]] . A . #[[{1, 2}]] + 
       b . #[[{1, 2}]] - #[[3]] &, Rest[xyz]]];
   
  quad = NMinimize[J, vars];
  \[Kappa]G2D = Det[A] /. quad[[2]];
  {\[Kappa]Gexakt, \[Kappa]G1 , \[Kappa]G2D }      ]
```

Now we calculate curvature and relative error for a set of randomly choosen points

```
\[Kappa]123 = Map[fun , RandomChoice[pts, 100] ];
error = Map[{1 - #[[2]]/#[[1]], 1 - #[[3]]/#[[1]]} &, \[Kappa]123];

{Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]} &[error[[All, 1]]] (* flinty's curvature *)
(*{0.157172, 0.368108}*)

{Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]} &[error[[All, 2]]] (* quadratic form approach*)
(*{-0.0725463, 0.111667}*)
```

Second result shows improved estimation!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest curvature notion is perhaps the combinatorial curvature for an assumed 2d-surface  embedded in euclidean 3d: for each vertex, map the edges to the nearest neighbours onto a flat polygon of triangles of equal sides and calculate the angular sum $-2\pi$ divided by the area. Of course, the values make sense with some noise only,  if the point cloud reflects differentiablity to second order.